# How to sort Android ListView by Column wise?

Tags: android, android-listview

I've a list view in that it contain a header (like addHeaderView(layout) and Header having three columns) and when i click on first column of header then the list is to be sorted according to the values lied into the first column, then if i click second column of header then list is being sorted according to second column and so on. But now its working like whenever i click any column the list is being sorted based on first column so how can i achieve my problem?

Thanks,
@nag.

Comment: look at my newly edited comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Put header for column title in listview.
2. for [multi column in listview try this.](http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/blog/2009/02/15/multicolumn-listview-in-android/)
3. to sorting listview column, sort the list (String array[]) you providing in listview.

Comment: ya i sorted by using Arrays.sort(list) but it'll sorting by using first column only but if i want to sort according to second column how can i do this?

Comment: I think you not getting, Make a custom adapter view in which you passed all the string array for your column and when the header column title clicked then call adapters notifyDataSetchanged() from which your adapter's getView() will called in that just sort the arry fro which the header title is clicked simple. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well in case like this in the listener you sort you adapter differently , that's it in case the  A button i pressed than you sort the adapter according some criteria A, if the B button i pressed than than you sort the adapter according some criteria B. after every change you call notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: that's ok but if i've so many columns then at that time how can i do this one, 've to write so many click events?

Comment: well you have to tall to program somehow that you want to sort deferentially , the program can not guess what you want to do, you must register listeners on the buttons