# Android How to sort list of items in list view by column

Tags: android, android-listview

Can any one help me how to sort list of objects when i click on the list view header.I want to sort list of items by column.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort Android ListView by Column wise?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7441189/how-to-sort-android-listview-by-column-wise/7441260#7441260) for more detail and answer look at my answer in above link question also check the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I guess it depends on your data. You could for example just call the database to get you a new cursor with the correct sorting order.

Or if you have a list sort it by using Collections. [Example here for a custom class](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/UseCollectionssorttosortcustomclassanduserdefinedComparator.htm)